# How to Telegram Login in a Spring Boot App?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, cryptography, telegram

I'm having some troubles with checking if the data I receive from a logged user are authentic or not. I'm following this short [guide](https://core.telegram.org/widgets/login#checking-authorization) from telegram.

**MyController.java**

```
@GetMapping("/checkData")
    public String handleTGLogin(@RequestParam Map<String, String> params) {

        String hash = params.get("hash");
        params.remove("hash");

        StringBuilder data_check_builder = new StringBuilder();
        SortedSet<String> keys = new TreeSet<>(params.keySet());
        for (String key : keys) {
            String value = params.get(key);
            logger.log(Level.INFO, key);
            data_check_builder.append(key).append("=").append(value).append(System.lineSeparator());
        }

        String data_check_string = data_check_builder.toString();
        logger.log(Level.INFO, data_check_string);
        data_check_string = removeLastLineSeparator(data_check_string);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, data_check_string);

        String secretKey = "ad5b4ae518c20"; //in my code i have the correct one, these are random letters
        String hmacSha256 = null;
        try {
            hmacSha256 = calculateHmacSha256(data_check_string, secretKey);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "HMAC-SHA-256: " + hmacSha256);
        logger.log(Level.INFO, "hash: " + hash);
        //These 2 logs should be the same string, but they actually don't coincide
        return "Received parameters: " + params.toString();
    }
```

**Functions**

```
public String removeLastLineSeparator(String input) {
        if (input.endsWith(ls)) {
            // Calculate the length of the input string
            int length = input.length();

            // Calculate the length of the line separator
            int lineSeparatorLength = ls.length();

            // Remove the line separator by excluding the last characters
            input = input.substring(0, length - lineSeparatorLength);
        }

        return input;
    }

private String calculateHmacSha256(String data, String secretKey) throws NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(secretKey.getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
            Mac mac = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
            mac.init(secretKeySpec);
            byte[] hash = mac.doFinal(data.getBytes());

            // Use Apache Commons Codec to convert the byte array to a hexadecimal string
            String hexHash = Hex.encodeHexString(hash).toLowerCase();
            return hexHash;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Why *hmacSha256* and *hash* are not the same? What I'm doing wrong? Thanks for any help!

PS: maybe this [python implementation](https://github.com/dmytrostriletskyi/django-telegram-login/blob/develop/django_telegram_login/authentication.py) is useful.

Comment: How is it different? Uppercase/lowercase, is the hash and check hash calcutated over the same string? So are the elements in the right order? If the order is different you will get a different hash.

Comment: One difference is that the python one always uses `\n` whereas you have `System.lineSeparator()` which could be different, depending on the system/os in use.

Comment: @M.Deinum the hashes are totally different (which makes sense, a single character can change the whole hash). From Telegram I receive the hash and I must calculate another hash based on the other params (like auth_data,username,id etc.). These two hashes should match but I'm probably making some mistakes when creating the hash from params. The elements are correctly in an alphabetical order. Changing System.lineSeparator() with "\\n" still makes two different hashes

Comment: The delimiter is `\n` not `\\n`. Looking at the PHP and Python samples instead of the secret key the hashed value of the secret key is being passed, are you doing that as well?

Comment: I'm not an expert in java but "\" is used as escape character so i must write "\\n" I think, anyway I'm gonna try with both and I'm gonna check also about the hashed value

Comment: The secertkey is the hashed value of your TOKEN to use with Telegram. So if you use your token as the secret key, then you are using the wrong thing.

Comment: Also see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57663716/login-with-telegram-with-spring-security which uses the token and how to encode it as a secretkey. This for the HEX encoding -> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9655181/java-convert-a-byte-array-to-a-hex-string (if you are on JDK 17 I would suggest to use the `HexFormat` class).

Comment: I'm using the hashed token, gonna check if i encoded it correctly though

Comment: @M.Deinum first, thanks for your time, secondly I have checked and everything seems okay, the only difference from the telegram guide is that i don't have a last_name parameter (because i don't have it on telegram), i don't know if that's the problem